# Katalon Studio integration with Squash TA

Tags: automated-testing, katalon

I have a pretty simple question: Can we integrate Katalon Studio with Squash TA?

If yes can you, please, give me some links to help.

Comment: I'd not heard of Squash TA before now but, having had a look through their forums, don't think you can integrate the two. Have you tried asking them?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : no. Squash TA currently provides connectors out of the box to

- Selenium
- Sahi
- SOAP UI
- Databases/filesystem.

There is some paid plugins available, provided by the editor :

- Ranorex
- UFT

As Squash TA is Open Source, you may write your own connector to Katalon.